# Android App: specifying EnvironmentalReverb settings

Tags: android

In my android application via C#/Visual Studio I want to attach an EnvironmentalReverb to my AudioTrack, to control basic the reverb parameters, like:

```
`
var reverb = new EnvironmentalReverb(1, audioTrack.AudioSessionId);
reverb.RoomLevel = -1000;
reverb.ReverbDelay = 60;
`
```

But the last two lines of code give me errors "bad parameter value". Apparently they only work for values from 1 to 8, which is nonsense, as RoomLevel  is from [-9000 to 0] or smth, and ReverbDelay can be up to 18 seconds.

What is happening here? Please help!

I tried different values but they did not work, accessing these fields in a way like  `reverb.Parameters.RoomLevel = -2000` did NOT give an error but it did not modify the value at all.

Comment: Please post your actual error message, you're most likely skipping over important info.  Also, ReverbDelay CANNOT be 18s, according to the spec it can be up to 100 ms.

Comment: Error is "Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'AudioEffect: bad parameter', when I try to set RoomLevel=-1000, which is certainly in a correct range.